# I have an error with my sql syntax. I want to delete a row in my database using a user input of a specified username

Tags: python, sql, flask

I'm creating a web application with a delete user function for admin users.

```
Form = UpdateuserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _username = request.form['chngUsername']
        cur2 = conn.cursor()
        cur2.execute("DELETE from users where username = %s"), (_username,)
        # cur2.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE username='"+_username+"'")
        conn.commit()
        cur2.close()
```

I expected the output to delete the specified row in my database where the username was the one that was inputted. However i get this error statement.
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")

Comment: Learn to use parameters and never have this problem again.

Comment: See the error message carefully: it says that MySQL server ran query with '%s' and that means it was not converted to actual username value.

Comment: I tried this statement (cur2.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE username='"+_username+"'")) and realised that the data it was pulling was all the usernames as a list.

Comment: This is the data that _username is equal to ((('admin',), ('Testing',), ('testuser',), ('NewUser',), ('Qwerty',)))